# Raspberry Pi wireless AP with user internet restriction

Tags: access-point

I setup a Raspberry Pi connecting to my home router using the eth0 interface and broadcast a SSID via wlan0 interface simply by installing the RaspAP (https://raspap.com).

Everything working as expected.

However, I would like this newly created SSID only allow device to access a specific IP address (e.g. 1.2.3.4 for my kids' school web server).

I tried to configure the UFW rules

`sudo ufw default deny outgoing`

`sudo ufw allow from 10.3.141.0/8 to 1.2.3.4`

I found that the rule only applies to the pi itself but the iPad can still access anywhere.

Any thoughts is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use `ufw` so I don't know how to use it. But it is a front-end for `iptables`, to make managing a Netfilter firewall easier. With `iptables` you can define rules for the INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD chains. You are using

> sudo ufw default deny outgoing

that should be a rule for the OUTPUT chain. You have to use rules for the FORWARD chain. Look at the synonym for the `ufw` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dnsmasq` to whitelist the domains/IPs you want and deny access to everything else. Edit the file `/etc/dnsmasq.d/090_raspap.conf` and add the following:

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
server=/some-website.com/9.9.9.9
```

The `address` line tells dnsmasq to redirect all sites to localhost. The `server` directive makes only certain sites use Quad9's DNS server at 9.9.9.9. You can add any number of these server lines to build a custom whitelist.

Restart dnsmasq with RaspAP or from the shell and check its status:

```
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
sudo systemctl status dnsmasq.service
```

Connect a client to the AP and confirm that your whitelist works.